# Помогите разобраться с кнопкой в NIB/XIB файле swift 3

Tags: swift, button, swift3, xib

Помогите разобраться с кнопкой в NIB/XIB файле. На TableView выходит клавиатура из NIB/XIB файла. Но нажатие кнопки ничего не делает. Помогите разобраться, даже на платную основу согласен. Срочно надо. Спасибо.

[Проект тут](https://github.com/zhanswift/CheckMath)

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Вангую, что нужно delegate использовать.

Comment: Там и так delegate используется. Но не работает ((

Answer (score 0):

1) `UIView` не может обрабатывать нажатия кнопок. Это должен делать `UIViewController`.

2) Советую использовать `IBOutletCollection` и туда добавить все ваши кнопки. Сейчас у Вас их 12, это уже много, а представьте 20 или 30. Вы же не будите для каждой вручную писать все. `IBOutletCollection` предназначена для таких случаев, как у Вас =) Хорошая статья на тему: [тут](http://nshipster.com/ibaction-iboutlet-iboutletcollection/)

Comment: Nib файл не может подгрузить UIViewController ошибка выходит